# Aspas duplas ao exportar arquivos

Tags: mysql

Podem me tirar uma dúvida referente a exportação de arquivos no Mysql?, já dei uma pesquisa sobre mas não encontrei nenhuma resposta...

Seguinte, tenho uma tabela que armazena o NOME de alguns clientes, preciso colocar essa coluna em um determinado layout para importar em outro CRM.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando vou fazer a exportação desses dados a coluna de NOME recebe aspas duplas e isso não pode acontecer porquê vai ocasionar erro ao importar no CRM.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Aqui esta o Load que faço para inserir os dados na tb teste2.

```
Load data local infile 'C:/sql/31.03/Nao_part02.txt'
INTO TABLE teste2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(nome,@dt_imp)
SET
dt_imp= date(now())
;
```

Todos os arquivos importados para a tb teste2 não tem nenhuma aspa dupla.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia do por que isso acontece ?

obg!

Comment: Sugiro que forneça o arquivo original C:/sql/31.03/Nao_part02.txt

Comment: Oi, Clarck. Editei o post e adicionei um print do arquivo.

Comment: Tente `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED OPTIONALLY BY ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alguém tem alguma ideia do por que isso acontece ?

Verifiquei que este problema acontece porque no arquivo de origem existem dois caracteres que não estamos vendo a princípio, mas estão presentes. Para ver esses caracteres, você pode abrir o arquivo com o aplicativo Notepad++ e verá algo parecido com o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso não veja os caracteres no aplicativo Notepad++, mostrarei como habilitar essa visualização no final da resposta.

Observe que no final das linhas, com exceção da última, temos `CR` e `LF` que são conhecidos também como `\r` e `\n` respectivamente.

Na computação, *line feed (LF)*, nova linha ou quebra de linha é um caractere de controle que indica que uma linha deve ser acrescentada.
Já o *carriage return* (CR, um comando que fazia a cabeça da impressora retornar para a posição mais à esquerda).

Saiba um pouco mais sobre os caracteres especiais

> LF (caractere: \n, Unicode: U + 000A, ASCII: 10, hex: 0x0a): Este é
> simplesmente o caractere '\n' que todos conhecemos desde os primeiros
> dias de programação. Esse caractere é comumente conhecido como
> 'Alimentação de linha' ou 'Caractere de nova linha'.
>
> CR (caractere: \r, Unicode: U + 000D, ASCII: 13, hex: 0x0d): Este é
> simplesmente o caractere '\r'. Esse caractere é comumente conhecido
> como `carriage return` ou 'Retorno de carro'.

**O Problema na importação**

O problema é que no momento da importação, está sendo informado `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` quando na verdade deveria está informando `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`.

**Solução para corrigir a importação:**

1. Altere a linha `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` para `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`
2. Verifique se a última linha foi inserida corretamente, caso
   contrário, basta acrescentar uma linha em branco no final, mas
   provavelmente não será necessário. Falo isso, pois podemos observar que na última linha não existem os caracteres de marcação `CR` e `LF`.

**Corrigindo dados já existentes no Banco de Dados**

Execute a consulta na tabela `teste2` :

```
SELECT replace(nome,char(13),'***') FROM teste2;
```

Visto que sua importação inicial considerou apenas o `\n`, significa que o `\r` foi incluso no banco de dados, a consulta acima evidenciará esse caractere conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Solução para os dados já existentes:**

Sugiro realizar um `UPDATE` atualizando os registros que possuem o `\r` da seguinte forma:

```
UPDATE teste2
SET 
    nome = REPLACE(nome, CHAR(13), '')
WHERE
    nome LIKE '%\r'
```

**Caso não veja os caracteres no aplicativo Notepad++**:
Habilite a opção "Exibir final de linha" conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte pesquisada sobre os caracteres: [EOL or End of Line or newline ascii character](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/eol-end-of-line-or-newline-characters/#:%7E:text=Notepad%2B%2B%20will%20show%20all,only%20show%20LF%20(%5Cn).)

Comment: Clarck, muito obrigado por sua explicação foi fantástica! Realmente os dados que preciso importar estão com \r e \n. Não sabia que o  critério de importar os dados era baseado dessa maneira, quando consultei a documentação não tinha entendido essa parte. Muito obrigado!